# c# twincat passing argument to class constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, arguments, cnc, twincat

I wonder what is the best way.

If I need to pass a class to a class constructor why should I use a variable inside my class.

Example:

```
using Beckhoff.App.Ads.Core.Plc;

Class test()
{
    private static IBAAdsServer AdsServer;
    private static IBAAdsCncClient _cncClient;

    public test(IBAAdsServer _adsServer)   //constructor
    {
        try
        {
            AdsServer = _adsServer;
            _cncClient = AdsServer.GetAdsClient<IBAAdsCncClient>("CNC");
            _cncClient.Synchronize = true;
        }
        catch (Exception Except)
        { MessageBox.Show("Error ! " + Except.Message); }
    }
```

Why can't I do:

```
using Beckhoff.App.Ads.Core.Plc;

Class test()
{
    private static IBAAdsCncClient _cncClient;

    public test(IBAAdsServer _adsServer)   //constructor
    {
        try
        {
            _cncClient = _adsServer.GetAdsClient<IBAAdsCncClient>("CNC");
            _cncClient.Synchronize = true;
        }
        catch (Exception Except)
        { MessageBox.Show("Error ! " + Except.Message); }
    }
```

I would like to use `_adsServer` in a lot of class not connected, how can I do that properly?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You can do that. You'll just lose the reference to it once the constructor is complete. Why do you say you can't do it? Also, why do you not just `GetAdsClient<...>` outside the class and push the result into your class?

Comment: Yes it was the other way to do this, and I actually do it like this but I was wondering if it was the good way to do it or if there is another better way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is like I do now.

```
using Beckhoff.App.Ads.Core.Plc;

Class test()
{
private static IBAAdsServer AdsServer;
private static IBAAdsCncClient _cncClient;

public test(IBAAdsServer _adsServer)                  //constructor
{
    try
    {
        AdsServer = _adsServer;
        _cncClient = AdsServer.GetAdsClient<IBAAdsCncClient>("CNC");
        _cncClient.Synchronize = true;
        Classtocall newClass = ClasstoCall(_cncClient);//Passing the argument directly
}
catch (Exception Except)
    { MessageBox.Show("Error ! " + Except.Message); }
}
```